# How to search for folders with specific naming convention and copy them to different location along with its contents?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a directory `F:\Input` with various subfolders in it.

I need to specifically copy only those folders which has same naming convention such as `India012345.zip`, `India09876.zip`, etc. These are really folders with unusual `.zip` in folder name and not ZIP files!

I need to copy those folders along with their contents (subfolders and files) to a different location.

```
CD /D F:\Input\
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /s /b /a:d "India*"') do echo|xcopy "%%I" "E:\output\" /s
```

This is my present code which copies the contents but not the main folders `India012345.zip`.

Folder structure of `F:\Input`:

- **Country**

  - **state**

    - **0021**

      - **op 1**

        - **qwerty**

          - **India09876.zip** *(folder, not compressed)*

            - **31-Jun-2016**

              - XML and PDF files
              - **vcxz**

                - 03-Aug-2016.zip *(file, compressed)*
    - **0031**

      - **op 1**

        - **India1234.zip** *(folder, not compressed)*

          - **31-Jun-2016**

            - XML and PDF files
            - **vcxz**

              - 04-Aug-2016.zip *(file, compressed)*

`India*.zip` will be unique in terms of nos.

It is not possible to rename. Please provide solution to copy as follows:

Folder `E:\Output` should contain after batch execution:

- **India09876.zip**

  - **31-Jun-2016**

    - XML and PDF files
    - **vcxz**

      - 03-Aug-2016.zip
- **India1234.zip**

  - **31-Jun-2016**

    - XML and PDF files
    - **vcxz**

      - 04-Aug-2016.zip

Comment: [Forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) maybe useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `India*.zip` directory name must be also specified in destination path and some more options of command **XCOPY** should be used like `/I` to automatically create the destination folder, too.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "F:\Input\India*.zip" /A:D /B /S 2^>nul') do xcopy "%%I" "E:\Output\%%~nxI\" /C /H /I /K /Q /R /S /Y >nul
```

It would be very easy possible to remove unusual `.zip` from the folder names during the copying process by using:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "F:\Input\India*.zip" /A:D /B /S 2^>nul') do xcopy "%%I" "E:\Output\%%~nI\" /C /H /I /K /Q /R /S /Y >nul
```

`%%~nI` is used instead of `%%~nxI` to get rid of "file extension" from folder name.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `xcopy /?`

And read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>nul`.

`2^>nul` is `2>nul` with redirection operator `>` escaped with `^` to apply `2>nul` on execution of command **DIR** instead of interpreting the redirection on parsing the **FOR** command line which would result in an exit of batch processing because of a syntax error.

`2>nul` used on execution of **DIR** results in redirecting a possible error message output by **DIR** to **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress it. Command **DIR** outputs the confusing error message `File not found` to standard error stream if it can't find any folder matching the folder name wildcard pattern `India*.zip`.